# Limit of checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, java, php, jquery, html

Good day! I currently have this code but it is not working and I can still select more than 2 even if I restrict it to maximum selection of 2 items. Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var limit = 2;
  
  $('input.single-checkbox').on('change', function(evt) {
    if ($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
      this.checked = false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Available Books</label>
  <div>
    <label>
      <?php foreach($collections as $collection):?>
       <input type="checkbox" id="blankCheckbox"  class="single-checkbox" <?php echo ($collection->book_status=='borrowed'? 'disabled':'')?> name='accession_no[]' value='<?php echo $collection->id ?>' aria-label="...">
       &nbsp;  
       <?php echo $collection->title ?> -  <?php echo $collection->author ?><br />
      <?php endforeach;?>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your code snippet doesn't work

Comment: You might want to consider perhaps rather than unchecking the a checked box if more than two are selected, when two are selected, disabling all the others by adding a disabled attr - `<input type="checkbox" disabled />` and then when the count drops below two removing them. It's a bit more of an elegant and user friendly way I think.

Answer (score 4):

referring to this [link Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vVxM2/)  you can find a way to limit the number of selected checkboxes if that is what you are searching for

```
var limit = 2;
$('input.single-checkbox').on('change', function(evt) {
   if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
       this.checked = false;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly note that the HTML your PHP code will generate is invalid. You have `id` attributes which will be duplicated, and also the `label` element needs to wrap each individual `<input>`, not all of them together. Here's a fixed version:

```
<?php foreach($collections as $collection):?>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox"  class="single-checkbox" <?php echo ($collection->book_status=='borrowed'? 'disabled': '')?> name="accession_no[]" value="<?php echo $collection->id ?>" aria-label="...">
    &nbsp;  
    <?php echo $collection->title ?> - <?php echo $collection->author ?><br />
  </label>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

The issue with the limiting logic now is that the checkbox elements are not siblings of each other, hence your use of `siblings()` will always return a length of `0` elements. To fix this, select the elements by class directly along with the `:checked` selector. Also note that to select up to the limit the check should use `>`, not `>=`. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var limit = 2;
  
  $('.single-checkbox').on('change', function(evt) {
    if ($('.single-checkbox:checked').length > limit) {
      this.checked = false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Available Books</label>
  <div>
    <label>
       <input type="checkbox" class="single-checkbox"  name='accession_no[]' value='1' aria-label="...">
       &nbsp;  
       Title #1 - Author #1<br />
    </label>
    
    <label>
       <input type="checkbox" class="single-checkbox"  name='accession_no[]' value='2' aria-label="...">
       &nbsp;  
       Title #2 - Author #2<br />
    </label>
    
    <label>
       <input type="checkbox" class="single-checkbox"  name='accession_no[]' value='3' aria-label="...">
       &nbsp;  
       Title #3 - Author #3<br />
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

check this code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Available Books</label>
<div>
<label>

   <input type="checkbox" id="blankCheckbox"  class="single-checkbox" name='accession_no[]' value='1' aria-label="...">
   <input type="checkbox" id="blankCheckbox2"  class="single-checkbox" name='accession_no[]' value='1' aria-label="...">
   <input type="checkbox" id="blankCheckbox3"  class="single-checkbox" name='accession_no[]' value='1' aria-label="...">
   <input type="checkbox" id="blankCheckbox4"  class="single-checkbox" name='accession_no[]' value='1' aria-label="...">
   <input type="checkbox" id="blankCheckbox5"  class="single-checkbox" name='accession_no[]' value='1' aria-label="...">
   &nbsp;

</label>
</div>
</div>
```

and this is your original code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label>Available Books</label>
 <div>
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach($collections as $collection):
    $i++;
    ?>
   <input type="checkbox" id="blankCheckbox_<?=$i?>"  class="single-checkbox" <?php echo ($collection->book_status=='borrowed'? 'disabled':'')?> name="accession_no[]" value="<?php echo $collection->id ?>" aria-label="...">
   &nbsp;
   <?php echo $collection->title ?> -  <?php echo $collection->author ?><br />
  <?php endforeach;?>
  </div>
  </div>
```

add this code bellow

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var limit = 2;

$('input.single-checkbox').on('change', function(evt) {
if ($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
  this.checked = false;
}
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: hope this will be work, for testing you can use my testing code then you can use your foreach code also